# Laravel join table

Tags: php, laravel

I have an Articles table and I am showing content on web in 3 different languages.
I need search on 3 different languages, Now I'm having only one language search So I implemented it like this.

```
$translations = Article::join('translations', 'articles.id', '=', 'translations.id') 
        ->where('value', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();
```

It's search but it's search different articles, Search don't work right, What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: you need to search in one language or multiple

Comment: on 3 different languages and i have controllers on main language but to other language search don't work am i using join wrong?

Comment: Your query is okay but where are you getting issue is not clear in your query. can you share table structure?

Comment: are you getting also those articles which don't have $request->search ?

Comment: no i'm not getting  i just added content on english language and then search it but i didn't get news what table structure ? articles ?

Comment: i think it is not selecting right foreign_key in tranlsations table

Comment: yes in translation table foreign key should be other field not the id field. like article_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In translation table, may be foreign key is `translations.foreign_key` so try this:

```
$translations = Article::join('translations', 'articles.id', '=', 'translations.foreign_key') 
        ->where('value', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();
```

Comment: I tried that i'm getting error nknown column 'translations.article_id'

Comment: what is the column_name you are using in translations table to store id  of articles table

Comment: can you share the column names of both tables articles, translations

Comment: i have this column in translations  /  table_name / column_name / foreign_key /  locale / value  i'm getting article id in foreign_key

Comment: than use 'translations.your_foreign_key' just like this -> `join('translations', 'articles.id', '=', 'translations.foreign_key')`

Comment: lol i'm getting in search one news 3 times :/ why ? (    $translations = Article::join('translations', 'articles.id', '=', 'translations.foreign_key') 
        ->where('value', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();

Comment: I think this is because of 3 languages. To search in a particular language you can use that in where condition. like `->where('locale', $language_id)`.

Comment: U mean like this:    $lang = \LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale();
        $translations = Article::join('translations', 'articles.id', '=', 'translations.foreign_key')->where('locale', $lang)
        ->where('value', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();

Comment: and sometimes its getting excerpt and body to but i need only title

Comment: provide fields in `select` just like Article::join('translations', 'articles.id', '=', 'translations.foreign_key')->select( 'articles.id', 'articles.title')->where('locale', $lang) ->where('value', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();
any field which you need, you can give in select. Make sure use the right table with field. If field in articles than articles.field_name or field in translations table then translations.field_name

Comment: i filtered ->where('column_name', 'title')  and now its getting only titles but if user will type on EN and GE langauges same content when i seach it its comes twice is it passable to filter unique ids in translations ?

Comment: ->groupBy('articles.id')

Comment: $translations = Article::join('translations', 'articles.id', '=', 'translations.foreign_key')->groupBy('articles.id')->where('locale', $lang)->where('column_name', 'title')
        ->where('value', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();  its errors on ->groupBy('articles.id')

Comment: use ->groupBy('articles.id') after where conditions
->groupBy('articles.id')->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();

Comment: Okay thanks again for help )